# Play Framework Ebean with weird behaviour, null when update

Tags: playframework-2.0, nullable, ebean

I am using Play Framework 2 with Ebean. 
I have a class say Person. Person have 2 interfaces, Passport and DriverLicence. 
Person have 2 variables, passportNum and driverLicenceNum. Passport and DriverLicence have their own CRUD, controlled by DriverLicenceController and PassportController. When I try to update driverLicenceNum from DriverLicenceController, it throws a ValidationException. I found out that the problem was caused by @Column(nullable = false). And I tried to print out passportNum value from update, and found out that in controller.update, passportNum has a value. But in Person.update, it's null. Please help. below are my codes:

```
public class Person extends Model {
    public interface Passport{}
    public interface DriverLicence{}

    @Id
    public Long id;
    @Required(groups = {Passport.class})
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Long passportNum;

    @Required(groups = {DriverLicence.class})
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Long driverLicenceNum;

    @Override
    public void update(Object o) {
        this.updatedOn = new DateTime();
        Logger.debug("Passport: "+this.passportNum); // NULL
        super.update(o);
    }
}

public class DriverLicenceController extends Controller {
    public static Result update(long personId) {
    Person person = Person.find.byId(personId);

    if(visit == null) {
        flash("error", "does not exist.");
        return DriverLicenceController.home();
    }

    Form<Person> personForm = form(Person.class, Person.DriverLicence.class).fill(person).bindFromRequest();
    if(personForm.hasErrors()) {
        flash("error", "DriverLicence has not been updated");
        return badRequest();
    }

    Person personObj = personForm.get();
    Logger.info("Password num: "+person.passPortNum); //display the number
    personObj.update(personId);        
    return ok();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is happening is this:

**1:**
`Person personObj = personForm.get();`
You create a new Person object based on the information in the form, this will set the person's driver licence, but not its ID and passport.

**2:** 
`Logger.info("Password num: "+person.passPortNum); //display the number`
You print out the passport number of the `person` object **previously retrieved from the database**.

**3:** 
`personObj.update(personId);`
This prints out the passport number of the `personObj`, which still hasn't changed so is null. It then sets the `id` of the `personObj` and updates it (in the super call).

This last step throws the `ValidationException` because one of the columns is null, which violates the nullable constraint.

You can simply solve this by doing the following before step 3 to avoid the passport number being null:

```
personObj.passportNum = person.passportNum;
```

If you have classes with many more fields and forms that alter only 1 of those fields, it's easier to simply get the object from the database, alter one field and to `update()` that object from the database. (you can also overload that if necessary) In your example your code would then be:

```
Person personObj = personForm.get();
person.driverLicenceNumber = personObj.driverLicenceNumber;
person.update(); // Id and other fields already set
```